# What role does string immutability play in the explaination of string references to developers?

Tags: c#, objective-c, string, language-design, immutability

In one form or another I encounter the following question often (posed, here, in pseudo-code):

```
String myString = "Hello"
someObject.stringProperty = myString
myString = "World"
```

> Why doesn't someObject.stringProperty now equal "World"?

There seems to be confusion about the role the following statement plays in the explanation of why this is the case:

> Strings are Immutable

What do you think?

If you think the statement doesn't apply, I'd ask you this: In a language where strings *were* mutable, and the assignment operator mutated their actual value (instead of simply changing the reference), would your answer still make sense?

**EDIT:**

OK, I feel the need to clarify some things:

1. I'm not confused about how strings, references, or assignments work. I'm perfectly clear on this topic. I'm not asking how strings work. I'm asking "What role does string immutability play in the explaination of string references to developers". We can skip the Ad-Hominem attacks that I must be confused.
2. I'm looking for a logically rigorous answer for the developer asking the cited question which doesn't contain, or pre-suppose, the immutability of strings.

A categorization of the existing arguments:

1. `String Immutability has nothing to do with it because the references are changing, not the values of the strings` This answer pre-supposes the exact fact I'm asking about.
2. `Assignment means assignment of references not assignment of values` Again, this pre-supposes the exact fact I'm asking about. There is no reason this *must* be the case for strings. It simply *is* the case for strings for performance and other reasons.

Comment: Steve, you seem to be confusing something very integral to the languages that you are working with. The assignment operator ('=') does not change the value of any object (immutable or not); rather, it sets the value of a stored pointer to an object in memory. Regardless of the mutability of an object, using an assignment operator to change the value of a pointer will not, and cannot, change the value of the object. For whatever reason, this seems to be mixed up for you (perhaps you were taught incorrectly), but that is very simply the case.

Comment: Besides, in your hypothetical world, if the assignment operator were to behave that way, the nature of the question were to change, and of course, the answer would be different. But it simply doesn't work that way, and you say so yourself in the question.

Comment: `There is no reason it _must_ be the case for strings.` It's not only the case for strings, this is how the assignment operator behaves in C# for _all_ types.

Comment: @Rob, so? That's not the case in C++ (where you can override the assignment operator). If the C# language designers had decided they didn't want strings to operate that way in the language, they could have done it.

Comment: @Steve: Right, but when you override the assignment operator, you can essentially 'break' the expected functionality of the operator. It really has nothing to do with immutability at all. This occurs with mutable objects as well.

Comment: Rob, your argument is `that is how the assignment operator behaves in C# for all types` yet you don't acknowledge that strings already have special syntactic treatment in C#... just look at how they are created - so I'm having a hard time understanding how this isn't perceived as a language design choice. The answer I keep getting from people seems to be "because that's the way it is". Yes, well, I understand that's the way it is... that's not the question.

Comment: Is there any language where using the assignment operator on a string variable mutates that variable's contents rather than changing what it points to?

Comment: @Gabe... Not that I'm aware of. But I'm also not aware of any languages with "mutable strings" (as their default 'string' implementation... NSMutableString / MutableString don't count here because they don't get the same special syntax as the built-in string)

Comment: Steve, to start off, no one is attacking you. Calling these ad-hominem attacks is a bit excessive. And second, it's difficult to understand what exactly it is your trying to get at. You say that it's clear to you how references work (and I have no further reason to disbelieve it), but if that's the case, what are we arguing about? You take up issue with the fact that 'it just is this way', but that's just it. There's nothing really further to discuss. Obviously, if things were diffent, as per your question, our answers would be different. But that isn't the case.

Comment: Furthermore, since you seem to be keen on citing logical fallacies, you must fully understand that there is no point in discussing the validity of any other case but what is currently the technical issue at hand, since that in and of itself is a fallacy. Your question seems to hinge on 'well, what if that wasn't the case', but that point is moot because a) it is the case and b) there's no point discussing any other possibilities because from a false statement, one can deduct any conclusion they want. *If the assignment operator worked differently, anything could happen, but it doesn't.*

Comment: @Itai. Thanks. I'm confused why people don't see this as a language design choice. Someone *could* have implemented strings to work in an alternative fashion - but didn't (for what you and I both understand are 'obvious' reasons). But, it *was* a choice. And that 'choice' which was made, in my mind, conforms to the definition of 'immutable'... and no one has proposed any argument which doesn't, at some point, make this assumption about strings - which, for someone who doesn't know it - I think, still, needs to be explained.

Comment: That's really the crux of my question. Can u explain why strings work the way they do without saying, at some point, "because the actual value being pointed to by the reference can never change and the language enforces this constraint". I don't think you can, and haven't heard anyone give an answer which indicates otherwise.

Comment: `there is no point in discussing the validity of any other case but what is currently the technical issue at hand` - Edification is the point. A deeper understanding of what is, what isn't, and why it is that way, is a fundamental aspect of growth. To understand that it is a language design decision, and to understand why that decision makes so much sense that every language (I know about) works that way - but that there is a language design world too - in which you can make up your own language rules and face the tradeoffs - is a crucial part of understanding what's really going on. IMO.

Comment: There's your answer. No, you can't, precisely because the language enforces this constraint. That's the whole point. If, for whatever reason, the assignment operator worked differently for just strings, it would create inconsistencies. The reason immutability plays no role in the assignment of strings is because it plays no role in that of objects; strings are objects, and the case for a string is just a special case for an object. If you were to make this design choice differently, then of course, things would work differently. But they simply don't. Does that answer your question more fully?

Comment: You just said it plays no role because it is the case. ??

Comment: In short, the point is consistency: in many languages, the assignment operator, references, and pointers work the same for strings and for objects because strings *are* objects. This is a design choice rooted in the quest for simplicity and consistency, and implementing only strings to work differently is, simply, a pain in the butt. Therefore, some design choices were made to have it this way, and for that reason, 'it just is.' This is the key point here. Would you like me to write this up as an answer, and not just a comment?

Comment: Itai, Sure, but other objects *are* mutable. I can modify all sorts of objects in .NET by using properties, methods, or direct ivar access to change the values of their instance variables. I can't, however, change the second character in a string. I also think your rationale for the reasoning behind the choice is incorrect (`This is a design choice rooted in the quest for simplicity and consistency`) If anything, it's because you can't possible allocate enough memory for an indeterminate number of characters, and any complex data structure would be too inefficient for a basic type like string.

Comment: @Steve let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1094/discussion-between-itai-ferber-and-steve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The role played by the statement in the explanation depends on the explanation itself. It could be harmful or useful, depending on the rest of the explanation.

Personally I wouldn't use that statement until fairly late in the explanation (at least these days). The immutability of strings just gets in the way somewhat - as it does with parameter passing explanations. I'd start with an explanation using a mutable class, like this:

```
House x = new House(Color.Green); // The has a green front door
House y = x;
x = new House(Color.Red);
Console.WriteLine(y.FrontDoorColor); // Still green!
```

Here I would explain that `x` and `y` are like pieces of paper with the addresses of houses on. The assignment in the second line doesn't copy a *house* - it copies the address of a house. The assignment on the *third* line doesn't change the color of the front door on the first house - it creates a *new* house, then rubs out the address on the first piece of paper (`x`), and writes the new address on. This doesn't change anything about the first house, or the second piece of paper (`y`).

I'd then produce a second example:

```
House x = new House(Color.Green); // The has a green front door
House y = x;
x.FrontDoorColor = Color.Red; // Repainting a front door
Console.WriteLine(y.FrontDoorColor); // Red!
```

This time there's only one house - if I paint the door of a house and you come to see it with the address I'd given you earlier, you'll see the front door is now red.

So far, so good. *Now* I could go back to the original example and say that it already looks like the first house snippet rather than the second one, so it behaves the same way. I can then say that string immutability means you can't even *write* code that looks like the second house example but using strings. So string immutability wouldn't have been *immediately* relevant to the explanation of the existing code, but it would still have appeared in the same answer.

(I'd also have to point out that although references behave like real-world addresses, I'm not claiming that they're the same as "memory addresses" or pointers. [They don't have to be](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx). I'm using the term in a strict analogy to the real world, and that's all. It's a downside of the example, but I don't think it does too much harm.)

I might *then* also talk about value types, and consider what would have happened if `House` had been a value type - as well as discouraging mutable value types.

To know whether or not my answer would still be relevant in a language with mutable strings, we'd need to know more about how string literals behaved. A language which was the same as C# in every way *other* than the mutability of strings would be an awful language, as you could write:

```
// Hypothetical bad language
string x = "dog";
x.MutateTo("cat");
Console.WriteLine("dog"); // Prints cat!
```

That clearly wouldn't be desirable, so presumably the behaviour of string literals would have to change. You also talk about possible changes to the meaning of the assignment operator, etc... it's hard to make concrete statements about a hypothetical language without knowing exactly how it behaves.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the equals sign in computer programming is more of an assignment operator than an "mathematical equality" condition.  That the string is immutable has nothing to do with it.  This is all about the equals sign being a "assignment" operator rather than a mathematical equivalence constraint.

This means that A = B; and B = C; does not imply that A = C;

instead it means

A has been set to reference the value of B, so B's value is now A's value.
B has been set to reference the value of C, so C's value is now B's value, but A's value remains unchanged

If strings were not immutable

```
String myString = "Hello";
myString.replace(3, "p"); // replace starting at char #3 (the second 'l')
System.out.println(myString); // would print "Help"
```

But since Strings are immutable;

```
String myString = "Hello";
myString.replace(3, "p"); // returns a new string "help" which is not assigned to anything
// since the newly returned string was not assigned to anything, it was garbage collected
System.out.println(myString); // would print "Hello"
```

Comment: Steve, in your last assignment, you change `myString`'s reference to that of "World" by using an equals sign.  By doing so, it would have no impact on what had previously already occurred, which was `someObject.stringProperty` being set to `myString`'s previous value.  The equals sign is an assignment operator, not a mathematical equivalence operator.

Comment: I'm not confused about how strings work. I'm asking about the role the statement: "Strings are Immutable" plays in a valid answer as to why this is the case.

Comment: It doesn't play a role in this case, because immutability of strings isn't even required for what you are looking at.  Immutability of strings has to do with changing a String's value after it is created, and the above example never does that, it just assigns the same immutable strings to a couple of different variables.  I am thinking you are confusing immutability with constant.  Immutable means the value cannot be changed while constant means the reference cannot be reassigned.

Comment: You're claiming it doesn't have a role because it is the case. The example above only doesn't do that because it is the case that strings are immutable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

Comment: I have added an example which would have two different outcomes depending on immutability.  You'll see that assignment doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: `You'll see that assignment doesn't have anything to do with it.` Only because you decided it shouldn't. Could you give an example with assignment then?

Comment: Now in your alternate world, where the assignment operator actually mutates value, your code wouldn't work; because, you don't have an assignment operator, only a value changing operator.

Comment: +1 BTW for your opinion, and for taking the time to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is that this example has nothing to do with immutability.

You have two variables originally containing the same value, which for a string means they are pointing to the same object in memory. You then change the value of one of the variables and point it to another object in memory.

It is no different than saying

```
int a = 4;
int b = a;
a = 5;
```

Or

```
string x = "Foo";
string y = x;
x = "Bar";
```

Or

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { Bar = 42 };
Foo otherFoo = foo;
foo = new Foo() { Bar = 17; }
```

The variables momentarily reference the same thing. They are not otherwise inextricably linked for all time. As soon as you point one to something else, their commonality ends.

Comment: You didn't address the final paragraph.

Comment: @Steve, if the variable held the value as in the actual string, then it's the same thing. Two distinct variables holding the same value. Changing the value of one does not change the value of the other. Whether that value is the actual value of the object (like an integer), or the value of a reference, it's the same.

Comment: If, internally to the language/system all strings were implemented as linked-lists of chars (instead of immutable null-terminated arrays), and the reference to the head node always remained the same, such that the value of the string could be mutated.... then..... ?

Comment: What are you asking? In a hypothetical world where the rules were different, then by definition things could be different. In such a hypothetical world, you could mutate strings and keep multiple variables each holding the same value even after overwriting one of them. You could have integers and strings and Foos linked for all of time. If you change the rules, anything is possible. However, in the world of C#, and in the example presented, the fact remains: immutability has nothing at all to do with the explanation.

Comment: But in a world where someone doesn't understand, anything IS possible. Only because (by design) strings were implemented as immutable objects do your statements make sense. This is the problem I'm trying to answer. You can't make your argument without presuming the immutability statement.

Comment: I'm afraid you are simply incorrect. If you don't understand the idea that you have two independent variables, and a change to one will not impact the other, you're just lost. Immutability has nothing, and I definitely mean **nothing**, to do with this.

Comment: +1 BTW for your opinion, and for taking the time to answer the question. - In regards to your comment: `If you don't understand...` yes, I do understand perfectly. No need for attacks. I'm simply approaching it from a language design perspective - and i'm trying to see it from the perspective of someone else. You're approaching it from a straight-forward "this is the way it works" perspective... and I already understand how it works.